# How to save the extract from multiple urls as csv?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python so please excuse my noobish question/approach.

I systematically want to scrape the website from a QSR brand to get the locations of their restaurants + some more restaurant related information.

Inspecting the website I found out how the url needs to be to access this information.

Therefore I created a csv sheet containing the unique identifier of each restaurant.

I created the following python code to

- import the csv with the unique identifier
- combine the two parts of the Url with the unique identifier from the csv
- request the content from each individual url
- write/save it to a csv file

Using the print command I can see that the script is successfully parsing all the url's to the command line.
The requests.get is also accessing the urls. In the end, the csv is only containing the extract from the last url.

What am I missing?
There should be somewhere around 1,500 entries.

I'm kind of assuming that I would have to define that for each requested url the extract should be saved to a new column?

```
import csv
import requests


> with open(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Brand.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
            urls = "https://locator.uberall.com/api/storefinders/04AxJXeSBFk4qtBbhQ9JCK1987mtnF/locations/" + row[0] + "?v=20230110&language=de&fieldMask=businessId&fieldMask=callToActions&fieldMask=city&fieldMask=country&fieldMask=descriptionLong&fieldMask=descriptionShort&fieldMask=distance&fieldMask=email&fieldMask=fax&fieldMask=googlePlaceId&fieldMask=id&fieldMask=identifier&fieldMask=keywords&fieldMask=lat&fieldMask=lng&fieldMask=name&fieldMask=openingHours&fieldMask=openingHoursNotes&fieldMask=phone&fieldMask=photos&fieldMask=province&fieldMask=socialPost&fieldMask=specialOpeningHours&fieldMask=streetAndNumber&fieldMask=timezone&fieldMask=zip&fieldMask=brands&fieldMask=customItems&fieldMask=events&fieldMask=languages&fieldMask=menus&fieldMask=paymentOptions&fieldMask=people&fieldMask=products&fieldMask=services&fieldMask=socialProfiles&identifier=true"
            print (urls)
            r = requests.get(urls)
            
            with open("results.csv", "wb") as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question or what part of your program is not working as you expect?

Comment: Sorry I've somehow overriden my question...Will include ithe question above.

Comment: because you are overwriting the "results.csv" file in each iteration of the loop!

Comment: use 'with open("results.csv", "ab") as f' That way the urls are appended at the end of the file instead of overwriting it

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
with open("results.csv", "wb") as f:
```

Opens the file in write mode, which overrites any data in the file. You are doing this every iteration thus only the last write is seen.

To fix this either open the results file before the loop, this will overwrite the file every time the script is ran

```
with open("results.csv", "wb") as f:
    for row in reader:
        ...
        f.write(r.content)
```

Or open it in append mode, which will append to the file every time the script is ran

```
with open("results.csv", "ab") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. Is there a way to define that he always uses a new row per scraped url? Currently everything is written in line/row 1.

Comment: @theDemnex You could put a newline at the end of each entry: `f.write(r.content + "\n")`

Comment: Hi @Jab, thank you! 

Unfortunately then I receive the following error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    f.write(r.content + "\n")
            ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes"

Comment: `f.write(r.content + b"\n")` I forgot you were writing bytes

Answer (score 0):

Usually `with open("results.csv", "wb") as f:` is used to write in binary mode. If you want to append each new line instead of overwriting the existing ones you should consider using `with open("results.csv", "a") as f:` or if you really want to write in binary mode you could use `with open("results.csv", "ab") as f:`